# column formatting options in psql/postgresql

Tags: postgresql, formatting, psql

As in oracle sqlplus, we have options of column formatting (like: `column c3 heading City         Format a20`).

I need to do this kind of data formatting with `psql`. However, after googling - I couldn't find anything for psql. Do we have anything/replacement for this in psql?

Comment: `psql` is a **lot** smarted about formatting the output compared to SQLPlus. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: some of my table columns have a lot of data..so when I run it from pgsql prompt - it's output isn't pretty and all of the things in 1 line. I want to see it in a pretty-managed way.

Comment: "All of the things" - which things? Can you show us an example of the output you are not happy with? Maybe using a pager [like this one](https://github.com/okbob/pspg) is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably should try `psql -x` like `psql -x -d "your_dbname" -c "your_query;"` or `\x` if you are already in `psql` shell. This will print every column separately in a new line.

Also try reading official `psql` documentation, where all the formatting possibilities are explained -- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/app-psql.html (according to your postgres version).

**Example 1:**

```
$ psql -d dbname -c "SELECT * 
                     FROM pg_stat_activity 
                     WHERE datname = 'dbname' 
                     AND application_name = 'psql'
                     AND client_port = -1;"
```

Output (hard readable, if monitor/terminal window is not too wide):

```
   datid    | datname |  pid  | usesysid | usename  | application_name | client_addr | client_hostname | client_port |         backend_start         |          xact_start           |          query_start          |         state_change          | wait_event_type | wait_event | state  | backend_xid | backend_xmin |                                                   query                                                    
------------+---------+-------+----------+----------+------------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------+------------+--------+-------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1322253912 | dbname   | 75924 |       10 | postgres | psql             |             |                 |          -1 | 2020-02-17 14:55:51.716436+02 | 2020-02-17 14:55:51.724092+02 | 2020-02-17 14:55:51.724092+02 | 2020-02-17 14:55:51.724095+02 |                 |            | active |             |     96305140 | SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = 'dbname' AND application_name = 'psql' AND client_port = -1;
(1 row)
```

**Example 2:**

```
$ psql -x -d dbname -c "SELECT * 
                        FROM pg_stat_activity 
                        WHERE datname = 'dbname' 
                        AND application_name = 'psql'  
                        AND client_port = -1;"
```

Output (much more readable):

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
datid            | 1322253912
datname          | dbname
pid              | 75952
usesysid         | 10
usename          | postgres
application_name | psql
client_addr      | 
client_hostname  | 
client_port      | -1
backend_start    | 2020-02-17 14:56:37.88717+02
xact_start       | 2020-02-17 14:56:37.894672+02
query_start      | 2020-02-17 14:56:37.894672+02
state_change     | 2020-02-17 14:56:37.894676+02
wait_event_type  | 
wait_event       | 
state            | active
backend_xid      | 
backend_xmin     | 96305140
query            | SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = 'dbname' AND application_name = 'psql' AND client_port = -1;
```